# Where is the form icon saved in a WinForms application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I don't know where is the icon of an form saved...

I actually search it in project resources and did not found it, also it is not specified any path to it into the Properties of the form, still it occurs on form.

Is it somewhere serialized ? I just trying to find it and modify it and be sure that the new added icon will stay there...

Is it enough to just set a new icon from the form properties of the form and that one will automatically be saved in the location of the old one ?

To be more specific I also added a picture having an example with the icon of a form that I am talking about.

[image]

Comment: Check your Form1.resx file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your form in the designer.  Open the Properties box.  Click the form to select it.  Look for the "Icon" element in the Properties box in the Window Style group.

If you change the icon via the Properties box, then look at your designer code, you will see something like this (Form1.Designer.cs):

```
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1008, 540);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnTestReplacePerformance);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.txtResults);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnGetMatches);
        this.Controls.Add(this.txtSource);
        this.Controls.Add(this.txtRegex);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();
```

And you can see that the icon (this.Icon) is loaded from the resources.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes i found it there.... but it has no path specified to it... i do not know from where is it loaded there , in the Properties of the form... is it serialized somewhere and loaded from that unknown location ?

Comment: @user5631730 : It's saved in the `.resx` file, like Lars said.

Comment: It's not specified in a path. It's in your resources. You can manually set an icon from a path, if you wish, of course, but you would need to be careful how you do that. The safer .Net way is to include your images in resources, then simply refer to them via that.

Comment: Ok... and when is it set into resources it is somehow automatically saved there... For instance if I modify the icon from the initial path from where the form icon was first loaded, keeping the same name of the icon, still the one from the resources will be loaded into the form, am I right ?

Comment: @user5631730 : Why don't you just try it? **I believe** the icon is put in the `.resx` file during compilation (and is just linked during Design Time), thus it is updated every time you compile your application.